# Como hacer una copia de NSUserDefault y restaurarla de nuevo en Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

no he encontrado nada con este tema, y quería preguntar si alguien sabe si se puede hacer y si es así como hacerlo.

Tengo mi objeto:

```
NSUserDefaults *alertas;
```

y quiero hacer una copia de el en mi base de datos, por si un usuario borra la app y mas tarde la vuelve a instalar, poder restaurar todos los datos sin perderlos.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios temas aquí que tratar:

1 - ¿Cómo vas a identificar ese usuario una vez ha desinstalado la app?

2 - ¿Seguro que esos datos deberían estar guardados en NSUserDefaults y no en CoreData?

Dejando de lado esto, si quieres guardar ese objeto en tu base de datos yo lo haría guardando cada uno de los valores, entonces:

```
NSUserDefaults *alertas;

for(NSString* key in [[alertas dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys]){

  NSLog(@"Clave :%@", key);
  NSLog(@"Valor: %@",[alertas valueForKey:key]);

  [self sendKey:key andValue:[alertas valueForKey:key]];
}

- (void)sendKey:(NSString*)key andValue:(id)value {
  //Aquí implementas la función para enviar tus datos a servidor.
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Es necesario identificar a cada usuario**. (Facebook, Twitter, User/Pass, etc)

La mejor opción es **enviar el valor al servidor cuando el usuario modifique cualquier clave que exista en tu objeto** alertas. De esta forma siempre tendrás actualizados los datos en el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

No te recomiendo usar la instancia NSUserDefaults para guardar datos ya que es un apartado de la misma aplicación para guardar sus configuraciones internas, como región, idiomas, configuración de SDKs, etc. Considera usar CoreData o algún otro ORM como Realm o Firebase, incluso podrías guardar tus propios ficheros y sincronizarlos con iCloud.
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html

Si aun así quieres guardar el contenido de NSUserDefaults, lo mas practico es tomar todo el contenido y enviarlo a tu servidor.

```
NSUserDefaults* alertas;
// Transforma el objeto NSDictionary en un JSON NSData
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[alertas dictionaryRepresentation] options:0 error:nil];
// Inicializa un string con JSON desde el NSData
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// Luego puedes enviar el string completo a tu servidor, alli lo puedes parsear y guardar en tu base de datos o crear un fichero y guardarlo.
```

Ten en consideración de que si un usuario borra tu app, debes proveerle algún método de identificación (Login de e-mail con contraseña, login con Facebook, Login con Twitter, etc) para que vuelva a recuperar sus datos, pero debes ponerte en el caso de que no siempre va a ser el mismo usuario en un dispositivo.

Espero que la info te sea de ayuda!